# XBox controller in while loop

Tags: xbox360

I have a while loop that goes for ever. The goal is if I press `A` button, a message should be printed out showing this button has been pressed `A has been pressed`. I've done the loop and connecting XBox controller but the problem is that the message is printed out many times if I press the button one time. My question is why the message is being shown many times while I just press the button one time? Should I make some kind of sleep?

---

Edit:
This is the part of the code

```
while(true)
    {
        if(Player->IsConnected())
        {
            if( Player->GetState().Gamepad.wButtons & XINPUT_GAMEPAD_A )
                std::cout << " A button has been pressed ..." << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "\nERROR: Connect XBox Controller ... \n";
            std::cout << "Press Any Key To Exit.";
            std::cin.get();
            break;
        }
    }
```

The result when I only press once.

```
Press A to be printed out ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
 A button has been pressed ...
```

Comment: Can you provide some of your code?

Comment: @user000user, I've updated the post.

Comment: For more clarification: Does the message stop printing once you release the button? If so, user00user's solution is enough. If not, then there's some different issue with polling (as I suggested).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason, why the message is printed several times, is, due to the fact, that you read the state of the button every loop. *Player->GetState().Gamepad.wButtons* gives you the current state of the buttons. That means, as long as a button is pressed, requesting the state and checking for that button will be true.

What you can do, is, declare a boolean variable on top of the loop, that saves the state of a specified button of the last update.

This could look similar to this.

```
bool btnADown = false;

...

while(true)
{
    if(Player->IsConnected())
    {
        if( Player->GetState().Gamepad.wButtons & XINPUT_GAMEPAD_A )
        {
            if(!btnADown)
            {
                std::cout << " A button has been pressed ..." << std::endl;
                btnADown = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            btnADown = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nERROR: Connect XBox Controller ... \n";
        std::cout << "Press Any Key To Exit.";
        std::cin.get();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked but I still don't understand why. Is there another way to overcome this problem? Or should sleep function do the trick?

Comment: This might just be working around the actual issue. Does this work on multiple key presses, i.e. is `btnADown = false;` ever executed?

Comment: @CroCo This works, because once the button is down, _btnADown_ becomes true and thus, the message will not be printed anymore, until the key has been released and the *else* part will be executed/ _btnADown_ will become false. A sleep function should be avoided, because you never know, how long a user will hold down a button.

Comment: @Mario This does work for multiple key presses. If the button XINPUT_GAMEPAD_A is not pressed, the *if* statement will become false and thus the *else* statement will be executed.

Comment: @user000user, this means I have to do this for every button and joy stick?

Comment: Right, because depending on the speed of your program, the loop will be executed several times during a single key press.

Comment: @user000user, I used this solution in GLUT to move a robot but I got same problem. It is weird because this solution works in console application but not working when I use it in `Display()`